# Firebase Database, display data at second app load

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to store the data from my app.
Right now I can manage to save and delete my data inside Firebase database. My database structure is:

[image: screenshot]

I'm facing the following problem: once app loads i'm able to save and display the data entered in Firebase, on the `UITableView`, but if I reload and open again the app the `UITableView` is empty. I would like to display the data  stored in the database.

Here my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

var emptyArray = [String] ()
var depAirp : String = ""
var destAirp : String = ""
var routeName : String = ""
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var keyArray = [String] ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate=self
    tableView.dataSource=self
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

    // //create array for table view to be dispaly from fire base
    ref.child("Rotta").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let post = snapshot.value as? String
        if let actualPost = post {
        self.emptyArray.append(actualPost)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

}
 // display array on table view
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath)
                    let text = emptyArray[indexPath.row]
                    cell.textLabel?.text=text
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return emptyArray.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
//delate data at table view 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        emptyArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        ref.child("Rotta").child(routeName).removeValue()
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

}
   // button take data from 2 text field and save into the var and create the name for the routing name

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
    depAirp = textField1.text!
    destAirp = textField2.text!
    view.endEditing(true)
    routeName=("\(depAirp)-\(destAirp)")
    ref.child("Rotta").child(routeName).setValue(routeName)
    ref.child("Rotta").child(routeName).child("Dep Airport").setValue(depAirp)
    ref.child("Rotta").child(routeName).child("Dest Airport").setValue(destAirp)
    print(routeName)
    textField1.text=""
    textField2.text=""
    view.endEditing(true)

}
}
```

Comment: I don't see any hint suggesting that you are updating your database with a selected record.  I don't know what the button1 IBAction is for, either.

Comment: Are you removing your observer Somewhere ? how do you reload TableView ? try calling your observer in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

You have used `observe`, what that does it reads data once (in your case when you pressed run on the simulator) and then it continuously listens for changes, so when you close and open the app nothing is loaded on your `UITableView` as it has already been loaded once and no changes have been made.

You have two options:

1. Detach the listener when you leave the `ViewController`. See more here on https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write under detach listeners.
2. Instead of `observe` use `observeSingleEvent`. This will be called once and then get removed automatically.

You know the requirements of your app, you need to evaluate which approach is the suitable once.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove below code from `viewDidLoad()` and put it inside `viewWillAppear()`, as below:

```
ref.child("Rotta").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    let post = snapshot.value as? String
    if let actualPost = post {
    self.emptyArray.append(actualPost)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
```